# Magento solr search - how to add custom field to product search index

Tags: magento, search, solr

I have enterprise magento 1.10 and I need to add custom field to solr index in order to to have better search results. This custom field should contain category names for indexed product.

I need to know which part of magento I need to amend. I modified method Enterprise_Search_Model_Resource_Index::_getCatalogCategoryData which actualy produces some category related data but my new field doesnt appear in message to sorl.

Have I miss something?

Also I have some notes here, maybe it would someone help http://docs.nostresscommerce.com:8090/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2490371

My output of rewrited Enterprise_Search_Model_Resource_Index::_getCatalogCategoryData, and I need category_name_level_* in solr.

```
  [result] => Array
        (
            [12227] => Array
                (
                    [#categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [3] => 3235
                            [7] => 2765
                            [10] => 6672
                        )

                    [#show_in_categories] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 6671
                            [2] => 6670
                            [4] => 3224
                            [5] => 3199
                            [6] => 3191
                            [8] => 2761
                            [9] => 2760
                        )

                    [#position_category_2] => 1
                    [#position_category_6671] => 120000
                    [#position_category_6670] => 120000
                    [#position_category_3235] => 0
                    [#position_category_3224] => 150000
                    [#position_category_3199] => 150000
                    [#position_category_3191] => 120000
                    [#position_category_2765] => 1
                    [#position_category_2761] => 250001
                    [#position_category_2760] => 250001
                    [#position_category_6672] => 0
                    [#visibility] => 4
                    [#category_name_level_1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => BCC Root Category
                        )

                    [#category_name_level_4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Huishouden
                            [1] => Top wasmachines
                            [2] => Accessoires wasmachine
                        )

                    [#category_name_level_3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Beste Koop Shop
                            [1] => Top
                            [2] => Wasmachine
                        )

                    [#category_name_level_2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Acties
                            [1] => Speciale informatie pagina's
                            [2] => Huishouden
                        )

                    [#category_name_level_5] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Wasmachines
                        )

                )

        )
```

Thanks a lot,
Jaro.

I found a solution

```
class Xyz_Solrsearch_Model_Resource_Engine extends Enterprise_Search_Model_Resource_Engine {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_advancedDynamicIndexFields[] = '#category_name_level_';
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```